# Why the limitations on Dictionary sorting in C#?

Tags: c#, sorting, dictionary

Have recently taken over an application from another developer who was very Dictionary-happy, using them all over the place with varying degrees of appropriateness.

I've gotten an awful lot of change requests to having various things in the application sorted, which is obviously a problem since you can't sort a Dictionary. I knew that: I've been bitten by it before, and it's one reason I avoid Dictionaries unless there's really no other solution.

What I didn't expect was how limited SortedDictionary was in the sense that, out of the box, it only sorts by Key and only sorts in one direction.

I'm not particularly interested in solutions to this: SO is already full of them. I'm just curious as to whether there are good technical or architectural reasons as to *why* there's still no functionality in C# to sort a Dictionary, and why the default behaviours on SortedDictionary are so limited?

EDIT: A specific example was called for, so here's one I'm working on. Bear in mind I'm not looking for a solution here (I created an `IComparer` to do the job in real life) - this is just for illustration.

In this instance, it's a WPF application and the Dictionary is used as a way of storing Key/Value pairs together so that the user interface can create a combobox with `DisplayMemberPath="Key" SelectedValuePath="Value`".

```
Dictionary<string, int> JobsDict = rep.Jobs_Get()
                                     .Where(x => x.MemberID == SelectedMemberID)
                                     .ToDictionary(x => x.Description, x => x.JobID);

//Jobs is a property of type SortedDictionary<string, int> that the UI binds to
Jobs = new SortedDictionary<string, int>(JobsDict);

//what I'd like to do at this point is ...
Jobs.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value);
//so that the user sees the most recent values at the top of the list
```

Comment: What do you mean by "only sorts in one direction"? You can specify an `IComparer<TKey>` and therefore sort however you like - still based on the key though.

Comment: Because the dictionary uses a hash-table that does not guarantee any order of items, while sorted dictionary uses some kind of balanced tree (RB-tree, probably?), which uses comparer for keys. That's just how those data structures work...

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes, I get that. But it'd be an awful lot easier to just call LINQ .OrderBy or .OrderByDescending, or perhaps just .Reverse in some cases. I'm just curious as to why these shorthand options aren't available.

Comment: @MattThrower sorting per-call is different to having data **stored** in order

Comment: I suggest you update the question with *specific* examples of what you'd want to be available, bearing in mind Marc's comment about storage vs "as you go" ordering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, dictionary types are implemented as a *hash table* for efficiency.  Because it is the hash function that determines which bucket the item goes into, and not the order of addition to the collection, we have no way of even keeping track of the order. To do so would hurt the effectiveness of the dictionary, at which point you might as well go back to a list / array.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the answer above:

If you do want to have multiple sort orders for a list without having to resort multiple times, you can do so readily easily by creating an integer array of indices for each sort order.

Then you sort the index arrays in the order that you want the original list of items (and you don't sort the original list at all).

You would only do something like this if you were using the items in sorted order multiple times without changing the data in the source collection. Otherwise, you'd end up resorting too much and you might as well just use `.OrderBy` on demand.

Here's some sample code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    sealed class Item
    {
        public int Number1;
        public int Number2;

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("Number1 = {0}, Number2 = {1}", Number1, Number2);
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        private void run()
        {
            var data = createTestData();

            var sort1 = Enumerable.Range(0, data.Count).ToArray(); // Indices to use to sort list by Number1.
            var sort2 = Enumerable.Range(0, data.Count).ToArray(); // Indices to use to sort list by Number1.

            Array.Sort(sort1, (a, b) => (data[a].Number1 - data[b].Number1));
            Array.Sort(sort2, (a, b) => (data[a].Number2 - data[b].Number2));

            Console.WriteLine("Original data:");

            foreach (var element in data)
                Console.WriteLine(element);

            Console.WriteLine("\nSorted by Number1:");

            foreach (var index in sort1)
                Console.WriteLine(data[index]);

            Console.WriteLine("\nSorted by Number2:");

            foreach (var index in sort2)
                Console.WriteLine(data[index]);
        }

        static List<Item> createTestData()
        {
            return new List<Item>
            {
                new Item {Number1 = 2, Number2 = 3},
                new Item {Number1 = 1, Number2 = 4},
                new Item {Number1 = 4, Number2 = 1},
                new Item {Number1 = 7, Number2 = 6},
                new Item {Number1 = 5, Number2 = 7},
                new Item {Number1 = 6, Number2 = 5},
                new Item {Number1 = 3, Number2 = 2},
            };
        }

        static void Main()
        {
            new Program().run();
        }
    }
}
```